Messanger app with complex deletion preemption for households with shared phones and people deleting other people's received messages
In some households, someone may use WhatsApp to send and receive messages, having, conversations, with another person, while other household members delete the messages.
This means the person cannot go back and cherish messages thinking about the message history and working their ways and mind, around, them.
In order to prevent this situation, it would be nice to have a messager application that works as follows:
A sends a message to B, and the message is stored on the server in the cloud, read by B, and kept
In order to delete a message, B has to send A a delete request token
Only when A receives the delete request token and decides to approve the deletion, can a token be sent from A to B and can B then delete the message.
Otherwise, the message cannot be deleted by B.
This, means, the message that B receives, stored, on the server, is kept by B, and cannot be deleted by other household members getting a hold of the phone and it's messenger app and deleting the messages.
Deleting messages makes B lose a sense of connection with A, and, all memories, concerning, A, are then related to the past (and, not to the present, message, interaction, between B and A).
This, also means, that if a past interaction between A and B was bad, or, if B, only encourages bad memories, B cannot have good memories of A, and, will tend, to work with those bad memories.
This, also means, B will have, negative, thoughts.
Especially if they are preempted from working in alternative activities.
So, my question is, where can I find such a replacement app for Whatsapp, that prevents these message deletion scenarios, by working as described?
Thanks.
Furthermore, it would be good if you could authenticate message authenticity via fingerprint authentication, to prevent the other party not knowing who the message is from.
The household members deleting the messages could claim the messages are deleted to save space on the device. In order to prevent, this, messages should be stored on the server and downloaded as per space considerations, after, making them invisible on the device, but, still, available, and, downloadable, on/from the server.
Thank you very much for pointers to messager applications supporting these features and for your implementations.
Thanks.
